# SVN Repository Restore message "failed to load module for fs type 'bdb'"

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, berkeley-db, fsfs

I was using Visual SVN Server 2.X , but due to virus i lost my windows. after new installation when i try to connect existing repository with new Visual SVN Server 3.x i got an error **"failed to load module for fs type 'bdb'"**.after searching alot i am unable to  resolve this issue.plz suggest something to solve this issue.

Comment: I guess that such question has to be asked on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should install the same version as you had before you lost your original machine. You can download get an older VisualSVN Server version at https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/

   You can upgrade your VisualSVN Server instance later. Make sure to read the upgrade guide at https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00082/
2. VisualSVN Server does not support BDB fs-type repositories. Are you sure that the repository that errors our was ever hosted on VisualSVN Server? If not, then you might be required to dump-load the repository to FSFS fs-type repository. See the KB article "How can I import my existing repository into newly installed VisualSVN Server?" at https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/

   To determine the fs-type of your repository run the following command:
   `type <path-to-repository>\db\fs-type`.

   What is the result? Is it `fsfs` or `bdb`?